# Make does not rebuild transitive dependencies of pattern rules on change, why?

Tags: make, gnu-make

I have a Makefile, roughly so:

```
.PRECIOUS: %.a %.b %.c

%.a:
        touch $@

%.b: %.a
        touch $@

%.c: %.b
        touch $@
```

If I create "test.c" with a `make test.c`, all the 3 files (`test.a`, `test.b`, `test.c`) are created correctly. However, if I now remove `test.a`, and then I try to re-create `test.c`, then nothing happens.

Reason is obvious: because `test.c` depends only on `test.b`, and `test.b` was not changed, not rebuild is needed. However, `test.b` should be rebuilt because `test.a` disappeared, and that should spread to `test.c` as well. I find this behavior as a highly un-intuitive side effect.

Can I somehow let make to handle "transitive" dependencies on the intuitive way? (I.e. after the deletion of `test.a`, all the targets must be rebuilt.)

The problem happens only with pattern rules.

(P.s. I need all the intermediate files, this is why the PRECIOUS. Default behavior of the GNU Make is that it deletes the intermediary files.)

Comment: The obvious solution is that I make "c" dependent of both "a" and "b". That works, question is, does a better solution exist. If not, then this solution is an acceptable answer.

Comment: I do not see the behavior you describe using GNU make 4.3. `make c` triggers `touch a`, `touch b`, `touch c`.  If I then `rm a; make c`, I again get `touch a`, `touch b`, `touch c`.  If I `rm b; make c`, then I get only `touch b` and `touch c`.  That seems to be the desired behavior.

Comment: @AndyDalton You were right. Actually, my original Makefile had some % and after editing the question, the current version already shows the problem. Funny thing is that the direct dependencies are yes, rebuilt, only the transitive deps are not. I updated the minimal example and so also the question.

Comment: With that update, I see the behavior that you're describing.  Unfortunately, I don't have any suggestions :/

Comment: What about adding the directory test.a belongs to as a prerequisite to the target ?

Comment: @MC68020 Suboptimal workaround (any new file creation/deletion/rename would let rebuilt everything). But the idea is very nice and tricky :-)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use a phony target traditionally named [FORCE](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html) as a prerequisite for `%.a`, so
that it is always built if it doesn't exist. Also, gnu make has a
`.NOTINTERMEDIATE` [special target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html) that does not delete the intermediate
files (but will do so on error and interrupt, unlike `.PRECIOUS`).

```
.NOTINTERMEDIATE: %.a %.b %.c
.PHONY: FORCE
%.a: FORCE
    touch $@
%.b: %.a
    touch $@
%.c: %.b
    touch $@
```

Comment: Which version of `make` are you using?  With GNU make 4.4.1, using what you've posted if I do `make test.c`, it ends up touching `Makefile.a`, `Makefile.b`, `Makefile.c`, then tries to build an executable named `Makefile` (overwriting the makefile).

Comment: Yes, make always tries to update the makefilie first, and the built-in rules thinks `Makefile` can be built from `Makefile.c` and hence the cascade. You can add `Makefile` to the `.PHONY` target to avoid this. If the target `%.c` had been `%.d` for example, this wouldn't happen.